# SQL Server : The pros and cons of certificate and symmetric key

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I would like to know the pros and cons between of its. Which is better in specific work?

Answer (score 0):

Usually, a [symmetric-key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188357.aspx) is used for encrypting and decrypting data.

The associated encryption key in turn can be wrapped using - a certificate (that is a public-key and private-key pair) or using a password or using a different symmetric key.

Also see :

[Encryption Hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189586.aspx).

[Encrypt-by-key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx)